# How to control join conditionals in Django query? Or how to filter a query based on values of django-mptt ancestor fields?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-mptt, mptt

I'm using django-mppt to allow Project models to have parent Projects in my application (and Tasks belong to Projects). Each Project has a status, and I'm trying to query for **all Projects which are active and whose ancestors are *all* active as well** (and eventually, for the Tasks which belong to these Projects).

### Models

```
class Project(MPTTModel):
    ...
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Active'),
        (2, 'Paused'),
        (3, 'Completed'),
    )
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    ...

class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    project = TreeForeignKey(Project, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

### Raw SQL

I've managed to construct a raw SQL query that gets me all Projects which are active and whose ancestors are all also active. I'm doing this by constructing a LEFT OUTER JOIN for any *inactive* ancestors, and checking that the result IS NULL, i.e. that there exist no inactive ancestors (not sure if this is the best way).

```sql
SELECT p.* FROM projects_project p
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_project a  -- join inactive ancestors
    ON a.tree_id = p.tree_id AND a.lft <= p.lft AND a.rght >= p.rght  -- must be MPTT ancestor
    AND a.status != 1  -- must not be active
WHERE p.status = 1 AND a.id IS NULL  -- i.e. is active and has no inactive ancestors
```

### Django Query?

Is it possible to write this -- or something functionally equivalent -- as a Django query?

I know that I can use [Q Objects for complex lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and I've looked at [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions)... but F() expressions don't seem to help insofar as a Project's ancestors are not accessible off a foreign key of a Project, but rather require a JOIN or subquery with filters based on the `tree_id`, `lft` and `rght` fields, as far as I understand MPTTs.

I've come up with this Django snippet, where given that I *already* have a Project p as an object, I can construct a Django query for any inactive ancestors of that particular object:

```
Project.objects.filter(tree_id=p.tree_id, lft__lte=p.lft, rght__gte=p.rght).exclude(status=1)
```

But then I need to have the Project already retrieved from the database to check its ancestry like that...

How can I use that snippet as part of a filter in join or subquery, so I can retrieve *all* relevant projects (i.e. active and have no inactive ancestors) in a single query, like the raw SQL above?

(Then, how might I query for all tasks that belong to an active project with no inactive ancestors?)

Comment: You can create a queryset, and pass it as an argument to a filter expression. The ORM is pretty good at doing stuff with that. (Note: I'm not really sure it will help in your case, but you may know).

Comment: Oh, hmm... when you say that "the ORM is pretty good at doing stuff with that," do you mean that through smart/lazy evaluation, it might actually end up being fewer queries (if not a single query)?

That is, just because I create a QuerySet, it doesn't mean there's actually a separate query being executed, right?

Hmm... going to play with this.

Comment: Yeah, it will often be able to use a sub-query, and will be lazily evaluated. It is possible to make _really_ bad queries this way: in some cases `.prefetch_related()` can actually be faster than doing joins, for instance, even though it runs more queries.